# joins on multiple related tables

Tags: join, inner-join, correlation, correlated-subquery

I have 3 table customer (customerid,name), customerbooking(bookingid,customerid), transact(transacted,bookingid,typeoftransaction)

I want to fetch the name of the ‘customer name’ who has the maximum typeoftransact=’current’. Customer table is linked to customerbooking via customerid, and customerbooking is linked to transact via bookingid.  Using join I am able to get the individual records, but unable to get the Max value

Comment: In other words, you want the customer who has the most 'current' transact records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this to meet your scenerio

```
SELECT 
  C.Name
, Count(BookingID) 
FROM Customer C 
INNER JOIN customerbooking CB ON CB.CustomerID = C.customerId
INNER JOIN transact T ON T.bookingid  = CB.BookingId
WHERE T.Typeoftransaction='current'
GROUP BY C.Name
```

Hope this helps